# Why are these divs not horizontally aligned? Why do they line break?

Tags: html, css, alignment

This HTML:

```html
<div style="border:1px solid blue; margin: auto; height:250px; width:600px;">
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;"></div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;"></div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;"></div> 
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;"></div>
</div>
```

Why are the red divs not in the same horizontal row and how do I get them in the same row?

Comment: Basic HTML 101, div's are block level elements. They will naturally display on top of each other.

Comment: Add `float:left` to the divs on `display:inline-block`

Comment: On a (very relevant) side note, you should avoid inline styling at all costs.

Comment: [`By default, block-level elements are formatted differently than inline elements. Generally, block-level elements begin on new lines, inline elements do not [...]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#block-inline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the divs are block elements and sometimes I use divs for containing menus. So you can add the style property called `display: inline-block` to the inner divs, and if you want those divs to be centered inside the container div you can use `text-align: center`. It will work on all type of block elements.

```html
<div style="border:1px solid blue; margin: auto; text-align:center; height:250px; width:600px;">
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px; display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;display:inline-block;"></div> 
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;display:inline-block;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you looking for:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.littleDiv {
        display: inline-block;
        border:1px
        solid red; 
        height:50px; 
        width:80px;
    }
</style>
<div style="border:1px solid blue; margin: auto; height:250px; width:600px;">
    <div class="littleDiv"></div>
    <div class="littleDiv"></div>
    <div class="littleDiv"></div> 
    <div class="littleDiv"></div>
</div>
```

> This has been possible for a long time using float, but now with inline-block it's even easier. inline-block elements are like inline elements but they can have a width and height.

However you might want to use `float: lefts` instead of `display: inline-block;`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it. A floating element is one where the computed value of float is not none.

Comment: if you're going to provide a class based markup (which is very good) you should go the full mile and delete the entire inline styles

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behavior of `div`s and all other block elements. To change it you have to either set  `display` to `inline-block` or `float` to `left` or `right`. (Setting `float: left;` will justify the elements against the left side of their container and `float: right;` will justify them to the right side.) I'd recommend practicing with `inline-block`. It's generally a better solution because it leaves the elements in the normal flow of the document rather than removing them from interaction with neighboring elements, as `float` does.

Answer (score 1):

Div Elements are block styled elements, by default. in order to make it in horizontal lvl make the style display attribute inline-block or float them left or right:

```
<div style="border:1px solid blue; margin: auto; height:250px; width:600px;"> 
    <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;"></div> 
    <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;"></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;"></div>
</div>
```

OR:

```
 <div style="border:1px solid blue; margin: auto; height:250px; width:600px;"> 
        <div style="float:left;border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;"></div> 
        <div style="float:left;border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;"></div>
        <div style="float:left;border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;"></div>
        <div style="float:left;border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one did the trick, the other answers was missing this detail  text-align:center;.

Thanks guys !

```html
<div style="border:1px solid blue; margin: auto; text-align:center; height:250px; width:600px;">
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px; display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;display:inline-block;"></div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;display:inline-block;"></div> 
    <div style="border:1px solid red; height:50px; width:80px;display:inline-block;"></div>
</div>
```